# What is the difference between num-executors,executor-cores,executor-memory in spark-submit from option(“numPartitions”,x) in spark.read?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read an RDBMS tables on PostgreSQL DB as:

```
val dataDF    = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                            .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2017")
                            .option("user", devUserName)
                            .option("password", devPassword)
                            .option("numPartitions",10)
                            .load()
```

The option: numPartitions denote number of partitions your data is split into and then process each partition in parallel manner, in this case it is: 10. I thought this is a cool option in spark until I came across the awesome feature of spark-submit: --num-executors, --executor-cores, --executor-memory. I read the concept of the three aforementioned parameters in spark-submit from this link: [here](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html)

What I don't understand is, if both are used for parallel processing, how different are both to each other ?

Could anyone let me know the difference between the above mentioned options ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `read.jdbc(..numPartitions..)`,  `numPartitions` is the number of partitions your data (Dataframe/Dataset) has. In other words, all subsequent operations on the read Dataframe will have a degree of parallelism equal to `numPartitions`. (This option also controls the number of parallel connections made to your JDBC source.)

To understand `--num-executors`, `--executor-cores`, `--executor-memory`, you should understand the concept of a `Task`. Every operation you perform on a Dataframe (or Dataset) converts to a `Task` on a partition of the Dataframe. Thus, one `Task` exists for each operation on each partition of the data.

`Task` execute on an `Executor`. `--num-executors` control the number of executors which will be spawned by Spark; thus this controls the parallelism of your `Tasks`. The other two options, `--executor-cores` and `--executor-memory` control the resources you provide to each executor. This depends, among other things, on the number of executors you wish to have on each machine.

P.S: This assumes that you are manually allocating the resources. Spark is also capable of [dynamic allocation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation).

For more information on this, you could use these links:

- [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)
- [Related StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871195)

---

**EDITS:**

The following statement has an important caveat:

> all subsequent operations on the read Dataframe will have a degree of parallelism equal to `numPartitions`.

Operations such as joins and aggregations (which involve shuffle) as well as operations such as [union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29978189) (which does not shuffle data) could change the partition factor.

Comment: Okay. So these two are independent of each other right ?

Comment: In a way, yes. The number of partitions control the parallelism. The above executor configurations control how interleaved the execution on the partitions will be.

Comment: `all subsequent operations on the read Dataframe will have a degree of parallelism equal to numPartitions` this is not true, certain operations (shuffles) change the number of partitions

Comment: I agree. I should have mentioned a caveat that operations such as `joins`, or aggregations (which involve shuffle) as well as operations such as `union` (which does not involve shuffle) could change the partition factor. Will edit the answer. Thank you, @RaphaelRoth.